# Deploying cgal docker

Tags: docker, cgal

I'm trying to deploy the [official CGAL docker](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal-testsuite-dockerfiles).
 From reading the `README` I understand that after downloading the specific image (e.g I want to open a docker with ubuntu16+CGAL and all of it's dependencies) using the following command:

```
docker pull cgal/testsuite-docker:ubuntu # get a specific image by replacing TAG with some tag
```

I need to install the cgal library itself using the

```
./test_cgal.py --user **** --passwd **** --images cgal-testsuite/ubuntu
```

The thing is that eventually I want to start the docker with an interactive shell, i.e

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/source somedocker
```

And I couldn't understand where is the generated image, after the CGAL installation script.

Comment: I don't know CGAL, but from what I see, the Docker image is just a means for running `test_cgal.py`, you don't need to touch it. Just pull your image, run `test_cgal.py` from the repository and that's it. What do you mean by "CGAL installation script" exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those images are not for running CGAL. They are only images we use to define an environment for our testsuite, and run tests in it, including compiling CGAL.
test_cgal.py will download the integration branch, which is rarely working as it is the branch in which we merge our PR to test them nightly. Don't use this to get a working CGAL. To my knowledge, there is no such image as the one you are looking for. No official one anyways.
Furthermore, installing cgal at runtime in this image will not modify the image, once you close the container your installation will be lost. You need to specify how to install CGA in the Dockerfile of your image and 
 then build it if you want a "ready to use" image.

You can use the dockerfile of the image you found to write your own, as there should be all the dependencies specified in it, but you need to edit it to download CGAL and maybe build it if you don't want the header-only version. This is not done in test-cgal.py or anywhere in this docker repository.